# Remove decimal places without rounding

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a function that converts 60000 into 60k or 60100 into 60.1k

But if I was to put in for instance 60123, it would output 60.123k

How do I make it output 60.1k without it rounding up like it does for number_format.

EDIT: Here is my function that does the converting

```
function format($val) {
$letter = "";
while ($val >= 1000) {
$val /= 1000;
$letter .= "K";
}
$letter = str_replace("KKKK", "000B", $letter);
$letter = str_replace("KKK", "B", $letter);
$letter = str_replace("KK", "M", $letter);
return $val.$letter;
}
```

Here is what I put to echo out

```
echo format(1)."<br>";
echo format(123548)."<br>";
echo format(1000000)."<br>";
echo format(1000000000)."<br>";
echo format(1200000000)."<br>";
```

And here is the output:

1
123.548K
1M
1B
1.2B

For the 123.548K, I want it to just be "123.5K"

Comment: Can you upload the script you have so that i can modify it for you ..

Comment: Added the script into the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```
function format($val) {
    $letter = "";
    while ($val >= 1000) {
        $val /= 1000;
        $letter .= "K";
    }
    $val = round($val, 1); // it provides the correct format
    $letter = str_replace("KKKK", "000B", $letter);
    $letter = str_replace("KKK", "B", $letter);
    $letter = str_replace("KK", "M", $letter);
    return $val.$letter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the floor function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php - note that floor(-1.2) = -2, if that could apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = 123;
echo number_format($value / 1000, 2).'k';
```

Edit (did not see comment about rounding). Treat the value as a string:

```
$value = 60146;
$value = $value / 1000;
$value = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '.')).'.'.substr($value, strpos($value, '.'), 3).'k';
echo $value;
```